# can I reboot my linux machine with a special ping packet?

Tags: linux, networking

A friend of mine told me a long time ago about how there was a system you could set up that you could specially craft a packet that you could ping a remote machine with that was all but hung but it was still listening on the network interface and you could use that ping packet to reboot the computer remotely.
 I Googled and I can't find it anywhere. anybody know anything about it?

Comment: You mean WakeOnLAN ?

Comment: no he means if you can reboot the machine remotely if it hangs, no, thst what your friend meaned was, that there was an PoD kernel bug existed which lead to a kernel crash, sofar the only thing is you csn reboot in case you csnt ping a host i. e.

Comment: see accepted answer for what I'm talking about. Thanks to whoever for downvoting the question because surely nobody else will ever be interested in the answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but rebooting a host with a magic packet is unreliable and risks denial of service attacks.  Out of band management is the proper solution.

Comment: Oh I know it wasn't you. You were helpful. Thanks. This isn't a high end server. No ipmi. I'll probably have to get a remote power switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of band access that at least forcibly powers off the machine is required if no one is physically present. The primary network and the software involved is not reliable enough to always provide you a shell over ssh. Hosts may be extremely unresponsive, or unreachable at all.

---

Regarding bugs and features that reboot a host with a packet or two:

Most [Ping of Death](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190986/how-perform-ping-flood-ping-of-death-and-teardrop-on-local-network) problems have long since been patched, as that obviously is a remote denial of service attack. As in [Linux 2.0 series and Windows 95](https://insecure.org/sploits/ping-o-death.html), and other old OSes. Dramatic name for just a buffer overflow, yes, but it was making boxes fall over.

On Linux, of course there exists [code that hits the magic SysRq key over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329081/4735500), which enables immediate reboot. Choose between in kernel from iptables or a userland daemon. Not available by default, because forcibly rebooting is dangerous and an obvious denial of service risk.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm looking for. basically if a machine is so sick it can't accept ssh connections, but enough of the kernel network stack is running that it can force a reboot if it detects a specific packet sent only by me from a network-local machine, thanks.